# how to set String in IndicatorInfo in xlpagertabstrip?

Tags: ios, xlpagertabstrip

how to set itemInfo text from string file xlpagertabstrip child title

```
 override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
            **let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "String" , ofType: "plist")
            let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
            let Data = dict?.object(forKey: "Main_Menu_Title") as! [String]
            let child_1 = HomeViewController(itemInfo: Data[0] )**
            let child_2 = SectraitViewController(itemInfo: "Home")
            let child_3 = InfrastructureViewController(itemInfo: "Home")
            let child_4 = TourismViewController(itemInfo: "Home")
            let child_5 = HomeViewController(itemInfo: "Home")

            guard isReload else {
                return [child_1, child_2, child_3, child_4, child_5]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the readme on [github](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) you need to add the `IndicatorInfoProvider` protocol to your child view controllers. Besides that need to copy and paste the function `indicatorInfo` into every child class.

The result will look something like:

```
class YourChildClass: YourViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

  // ... Your code here ...

  // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider

  func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: itemInfo)
  }
}
```